# HATEOAS link to method with optional requestparams

Tags: rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I want to link to a method that has the following signature:

```
public SomeResponse getSomeObjects(@RequestParam(value = "foo", defaultValue = "bar") Foo fooValue)
```

Now I want the link to look like this:

```
http://myhost/api/someobjects
```

I tried using `methodOn` from Spring HATEOAS's `ControllerLinkBuilder` as seen below:

```
discoverResponse.add(linkTo(methodOn(SomeController.class).getSomeObjects(null)).withRel("someobjects"))
```

But it doesn't lead to the desired link because a `?foo` is added at its end. How can I achieve the above objective?

Comment: Why does it matter what the link looks like? That's one of the nice things about HATEOAS; it doesn't really matter what they look like.

Comment: In this case it matters because the response needs to look exactly like that from the previous implementation (that wasn't implemented with HATEOAS) which did not add the ?foo part.

Comment: So you're trying to build a new version of your app which is backwards compatible version with a pre-HATEOAS application? Sounds tough. What do you hope to gain out of building a hypermedia-driven app in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since backward compatibility is such an issue for you, you could always manually construct your Link objects like so:

`discoverResponse.add(new Link(baseUri() + "/someobjects", "someobjects"));`

The other option would be to fork Spring HATEOAS on GitHub, build the project yourself, and change the way defaults are handled in `ControllerLinkBuilder`. I don't really know how you'd expect an out-of-context Link builder to be able to differentiate between whether it should advertise an optional parameter. In the HATEOAS world, if the parameter isn't included, the client doesn't know about it. So why even have the optional parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I know there are 7 years gone now, but I had a similar problem today which lead me here. In spring hateoas 1.1.0 the behavior is slightly different, instead it will generate [URI-Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_Template) by default for non-required @RequestParams:

```
http://myhost/api/someobjects{?foo}
```

If you don't want them in your link, you can just expand it

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("foo", null);
link = link.expand(parameters);
```

It will result in the desired URL

```
http://myhost/api/someobjects
```

Comment: While this looks like a good approach at first glance, I recommend not to do it this way.
A better way is to split the endpoints and have one with the filter behaviour and one without.
It will enhance the source-codes maintainability.